# value of $k$ for which quadratic expression is positive for exactly $2$ integer $x$

Tags: inequality

> The value of $k$ for which
> $kx^2-2kx+3x-6$ is positive for
> exactly two integral values of $x$ is

What I try:

$\bullet $ : If $k>0$, Then equation

$kx^2-2kx+3x-6>0$ and We have

$\displaystyle 4k^2-12k< 0\Longrightarrow 4k(k-3)<0$

So we have $k\in(0,3)$

$\displaystyle \bullet $ : If $k<0$ , Then equation have real roots for $4k(k-3)< 0$

So we get $k=\phi$

So we get $\displaystyle k\in\bigg(0,3\bigg)$

Please have a look on that problem

But answer given as $\displaystyle \bigg(-0.75,-0.60\bigg)$

Comment: "and We have $4k^2-12k\leq 0$": ? "Then equation have real roots for $4k(k-3)\leq 0$": ?

Comment: Hints: $kx^2-2kx+3x-6=(x-2)(kx+3).$ For it to be $>0$ for exactly 2 integers $x,$ $k$ must be $<0$ and there must be exactly 2 integers between the two roots. The answer is not exactly what you were given ($k=-0.6$ is allowed).